# Adding colors to a 3d quiver plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, mplot3d

I want to have colors corresponding to a colormap in my 3d quiver plot.  The 2d version of the plot has an optional array that is used to map colors to the arrows. How can I create the same effect in the 3d version?

Comment: Have you tried just passing it to the quiver plot as a keyword argument (`colors`)?

http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#quiver suggests that it passes keyword args on to `LineCollection`, which takes `colors` as one of its arguments.

Comment: Oh, it seems that it might be a bit more complicated than that, since `colors` has to be a list of RGBA tuples. However, if you know how you're going to map colors to your points, then perhaps you could generate the list. I think looking at the colormap routines might be helpful: http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html#module-matplotlib.cm

Comment: It might be worth opening an issues on GH reporting this issue.

Comment: There appears to be an issue already: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3382

Answer (score 10, accepted):

3D quiver plots are a brand-new feature in 1.4 it (and it's documentation) might still be a bit rough around the edges.  In this case we can try to use the fact that the quiver is implemented as a `LineCollection` which (eventually) inherits from `ScalarMappable` which means it knows what a colormap is and the returned artist has the method `set_array`.

Building on the docs [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#quiver)

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.8))

u = np.sin(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
v = -np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.sin(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
w = (np.sqrt(2.0 / 3.0) * np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) *
     np.sin(np.pi * z))

q = ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, length=0.1, cmap='Reds', lw=2)
q.set_array(np.random.rand(np.prod(x.shape)))

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, you will note the *heads* are a different color than the *shaft* which is due to a implementation detail of the way that it is implemented each part is drawn as it's own line.

Directly using the `Norm` and color map functions and passing the result to `colors` might be a better course.

Comment: What kind of argument does *colors* require?  I would have guessed an nxmxkx3 or nxmxkx4 dimensional array, but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 8):

You *can* use `colors` argument to specify custom colors for each arrow, although the way to do it is not at all straight-forward (as for *matplotlib 2.0.0*). I have specified in [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8484) the logic of how the quiver plot is actually drawn and a work-around to specify coloring. You can check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sytrus-in-github/a3b2ef4414fb144cb08505a060c99b18) for a simple example which can generate a graph similar to this one:
[image: custom coloring of matplotlib 3D quiver]

To summarize, here are the steps to follow:

1. suppose you have a list (of size x*y*z) of 3-tuples (or 4-tuples for RGBA) specifying the RGB values (between 0~1) of each vector to be drawn.
2. filter out the RGB (or RGBA) tuples corresponding to vectors of length 0 since they won't be drawn actually.
3. let `[color_1, color_2, ..., color_n]` be the list you obtained after step 2, you should specify `colors=[color_1, color_2, ..., color_n, color_1, color_1, color_2, color_2, ..., color_n, color_n]`since actually the "-" part (consisting of 1 line) of all the non-zero arrows "->" wil be drawn first, then comes the ">" part (consisting of 2 lines).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow this is absolutely, 100% bat-shit insane. Thanks, would have given up on coloring my arrows. Time to start learning plotly I guess!

Answer (score 7):

Building on @tacaswell and @sytrus answers, here is an example of coloring a 3d quiver plot

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Make the grid
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.8))

# Make the direction data for the arrows
u = np.sin(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
v = -np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.sin(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
w = (np.sqrt(2.0 / 3.0) * np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) *
     np.sin(np.pi * z))

# Color by azimuthal angle
c = np.arctan2(v, u)
# Flatten and normalize
c = (c.ravel() - c.min()) / c.ptp()
# Repeat for each body line and two head lines
c = np.concatenate((c, np.repeat(c, 2)))
# Colormap
c = plt.cm.hsv(c)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, colors=c, length=0.1, normalize=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: In case any vector has coordinates u, v, w == (0, 0, 0) the coloring won't work because that vector is not going to be plotted by matplotlib and the colors won't match anymore as previously pointed out by @wannes-goethals. Easy enough solution is to add some very small constant to your u, v, w coords, e.g. 1e-08.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on the answer from @slek120. I had an issue where vectors of length zero were present. These messed up the correspondence between the arrow tip colors. My solution is to give them a nonzero length and make them transparent. For some reason that I don't understand, simply discarding them didn't work. Adding a small change to the last part, a colorbar can be included as well. The colorbar asks explicitely for `q.set_array()`. This changes the color, but `q.set_edgecolor(c); q.set_facecolor(c)` lets you insert your custom colormap.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cmap = 'hsv'

# Make the grid
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.8))

# Make the direction data for the arrows
u = np.sin(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
v = -np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.sin(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
w = np.sqrt(2.0 / 3.0) * np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) * np.sin(np.pi * z)

# check what happens if all values are zero
# no quivers are plotted, colors don't match anymore
u[:,2:4] = v[:,2:4] = w[:,2:4] = 0
# change values that are zero to something close to zero
uvw = np.vstack((u[np.newaxis],v[np.newaxis],w[np.newaxis]))
norm = np.linalg.norm(uvw, axis = 0)
max_norm = np.max(norm)
mask = norm == 0
min_norm = 0.3  # you want every arrow to be longer than this fraction of max_norm
# rescale vs for illustrative purposes, so small vectors become visible
# and zero vectors become nonzero so colors of the arrow shaft and head correspond. Later these are made transparent
uvw = uvw + min_norm * np.tile(mask[np.newaxis], (3, 1, 1, 1)) / max_norm
# recalculate norms so you don't divide by zero
norm = np.linalg.norm(uvw, axis=0)
uvw = min_norm * uvw / norm + (1 - min_norm) * uvw / max_norm
u, v, w = uvw

# Color by azimuthal angle
c = np.arctan2(v, u)
# Flatten and normalize
c = (c.ravel() - c.min()) / c.ptp()
# Adjust for missing quivers
# c = c[np.nonzero((u.ravel() != 0) * (v.ravel() != 0) * (w.ravel() != 0))]
# Repeat for each body line and two head lines
c = np.concatenate((c, np.repeat(c, 2)))
repeated_mask = np.concatenate((mask.ravel(), np.repeat(mask.ravel(), 2)))
# Colormap
c = getattr(plt.cm, cmap)(c)
# set zero values transparent, you made them nonzero not to mess up the tip colors
c[repeated_mask, 3] = 0.1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
q = ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, cmap = cmap, length=0.1)
q.set_array(np.linspace(0,max_norm,10))
fig.colorbar(q)
q.set_edgecolor(c)
q.set_facecolor(c)

plt.show()
```

[image: Colored quivers with colorbar, zeros are made transparent.]

Answer (score 1):

As of the upcoming Matplotlib v3.8.4, the issue with arrowheads being incorrectly colored is fixed (see [PR #27754](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/27754)). An updated version of code snippets used in previous answers demonstrates how to set the color:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Make the grid
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.8))

# Make the direction data for the arrows
u = np.sin(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
v = -np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.sin(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
w = (np.sqrt(2.0 / 3.0) * np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) *
     np.sin(np.pi * z))

# set some vectors to zero as a demonstration
u[:, 2:4] = v[:, 2:4] = w[:, 2:4] = 0

# Color by azimuthal angle
c = np.arctan2(v, u)
# Flatten and normalize
c = (c.ravel() - c.min()) / c.ptp()
# Colormap
c = plt.cm.hsv(c)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, colors=c, length=0.1, normalize=True)
plt.show()
```

Produces: [image: Plotted Result]