# Matplotlib: Indexing color map

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a 3-d plot, but 4 of my 16 data points have invalid data from one of components (ie a vector has good x and y data but bad z data). I could just omit the points entirely, but then I'm getting rid of good data (in the x and y directions). Ideally, I would like to be able to change the color of the ones missing data as a kind of flag, so that they are still plotted but I can tell which ones are missing the data.

I have have very little experience with color maps, especially in 3-d. I've tried adapting solutions from:
[(python) plot 3d surface with colormap as 4th dimension, function of x,y,z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461452/python-plot-3d-surface-with-colormap-as-4th-dimension-function-of-x-y-z)
[Create own colormap using matplotlib and plot color scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834861/create-own-colormap-using-matplotlib-and-plot-color-scale)
and this one which seems the most helpful:
[Adding colors to a 3d quiver plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420504/adding-colors-to-a-3d-quiver-plot-in-matplotlib)
But I just want all of them to be the same colors except for very specific data points and I'm not sure how to index the color map.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D

def main():

    data = [[  1.52940323e-06,   3.30263460e-07,   1.23333738e-02],
            [ 0.00062357, -0.00061659, -0.21386033],
            [-0.00028384,  0.00088403, -0.21165629],
            [ 0.00225299,  0.00180132, -0.1964095 ],
            [-0.00066298,  0.00271399, -0.23091235],
            [ 0.00054687, -0.00063866, -0.24299   ],
            [ 0.00170783, -0.00140304, -0.09094558],
            [-0.00378669, -0.00592137, -0.07358853],
            [  5.84581114e-07,  -3.58723162e-07,  -3.08931350e-02],
            [ 0.0003522 , -0.00067592, -0.23933634],
            [ -5.84077540e-07,   2.08945622e-07,  -4.31579608e-02],
            [-0.00196888,  0.00261409, -0.28115362],
            [ -1.65606166e-04,   1.89755530e-01,  -1.49510581e-02],
            [-0.00048166,  0.00095946, -0.26929835],
            [  8.26054997e-04,  -7.75840354e-05,  -3.05118605e-01],
            [ 0.0018271 ,  0.00078126, -0.18526635]]


    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)



    x = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    y = [-0.002, -0.002, -0.002, -0.002, -0.001, -0.001, -0.001, -0.001, 
        0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002]
    z = [-0.0022500000000000003, -0.00075, 0.00075, 0.0022500000000000003, 
         -0.0022500000000000003, -0.00075, 0.00075, 0.0022500000000000003, 
         -0.0022500000000000003, -0.00075, 0.00075, 0.0022500000000000003, 
         -0.0022500000000000003, -0.00075, 0.00075, 0.0022500000000000003]


    # data[0]= [0]*3
    # data[8]= [0]*3
    # data[10]= [0]*3
    # data[12]= [0]*3
    u = [data[i][0] for i in range(len(data))]
    v = [data[i][1] for i in range(len(data))]
    w = [data[i][2] for i in range(len(data))]
    cdict = {'green': np.array(len(u)), 'green': np.array(len(u)), 
             'green':np.array(len(u))}
    cdict = {'red': [0],'red': [0],'red': [0]}

    ax.quiver(x,y,z,u,v,w, length=0.001, normalize=True, colors=cdict)

    ax.set_xlabel("X direction")
    ax.set_ylabel("Y direction")
    ax.set_zlabel("Z direction")
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This plots everything as red, instead of everything green and only certain vectors red. I'm not really sure what I'm doing, and any help would be much appreciated! (Also yes, I am stuck in the stone age with python 2)

**Edit:**
Inspired by the answer below, I created a mask for 'bad' channels, then created two plots, one with the good channels in blue, and one with the bad channels in red.

```
dead_chans = [1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]
good_u = np.ma.masked_array(u,dead_chans)
good_v = np.ma.masked_array(v, dead_chans)
good_w = np.ma.masked_array(w, dead_chans)

dead_u = np.ma.masked_array(u, np.logical_not(dead_chans))
dead_v = np.ma.masked_array(v, np.logical_not(dead_chans))
dead_w = np.ma.masked_array(w, np.logical_not(dead_chans))

ax.quiver(x,y,z,good_u,good_v,good_w, length=0.01, normalize=True, color= 
'b')
ax.quiver(x,y,z,dead_u,dead_v,dead_w, length=0.01, normalize=True, color = 
'r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: `cdict = {'red': [0],'red': [0],'red': [0]}` overwrites the previous dictionary with green colors. Also, you can't have multiple same keys. No point specifying `'green` three times. It is currently unclear what you want. " 4 of my 16 data points are missing data "... Where? I don't see the missing data. Also, if the z-value is missing how do you plan to plot it in a 3d system?

Comment: @Sheldore right, I am not sure how to index the color map without re-writing over the previous dictionary. Also a clarification about the missing data, I'm reading in data off of a scope that has a few channels that are dead, so I am essentially plotting noise instead of actual data, I just updated the question to be (hopefully) clearer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the z values to a `np.nan` instead of ignoring them altogether. Then you could use `colormap.set_bad()` to change the color of your nan values to something specific.

Hope that helps

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html

**Edit**

with help from this post:
[How can I plot NaN values as a special color with imshow in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578752/how-can-i-plot-nan-values-as-a-special-color-with-imshow-in-matplotlib)

Here's an example.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Set the defualt cmap for mpl
mpl.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'Blues'
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap()
cmap.set_bad(color='Red')

#Generate some data with np.nan values
x = np.arange(1,13,1)
y = np.arange(1,13,1)
vals = np.zeros([12,12])

for i in range(12):
    for j in range(12):
        if (i+j)%7==0:
            vals[i,j] = np.nan
        else:
            vals[i,j] = i*j

plt.pcolormesh(x,y,arr)
```

This code returns the following plot:

[image: plot with nans]

Comment: Ok, I tried it an it seems like progress, but now because the data is masked it's not showing up...

For reference I set w[0] = nan , then w = np.ma.masked_invalid(w), and the used set_bad and plotted it again using a cmap