# Matplotlib 3D Quiver plot makes the lines the right color but the arrow head the wrong color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to do a quiver plot of three arrows in the x, y and z direction with the arrow colors being green red and blue. For some reason, the lines are the right color but the arrow head is the wrong color and I am not sure how to fix. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
cols = ['r', 'g', 'b']

quivers = ax.quiver([0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1], colors=cols)

ax.set_xlim3d([-2.0, 2.0])
ax.set_xlabel('X')

ax.set_ylim3d([-2.0, 2.0])
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

ax.set_zlim3d([-2, 2])
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

[image: Quiver plot]

Comment: Why did you list 6 quivers when you only have 3 arrows?

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420504/adding-colors-to-a-3d-quiver-plot-in-matplotlib/43414969? It talks about the coloring

Comment: this looks like a bug to me

Comment: In `quiver`, if a list of colors is specified as option `colors=..`, color cycle is in effect for all line segments, including all parts of the arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `quiver`, if a list of colors is specified as option `colors=..`, color cycle is in effect for all line segments, including all parts of the arrows.

To get 3 arrows of different colors, you can use 3 `quiver` statements, each with different color.

**Method1**

```
ax.quiver([0],[0],[0],[1],[0],[0], colors='r')
ax.quiver([0],[0],[0],[0],[1],[0], colors='g')
ax.quiver([0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[1], colors='b')
```

**Method2**

```
fr = [(0,0,0), (0,0,0), (0,0,0)]
to = [(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)]
cr = ["red", "green", "blue"]
for (from_, to_, colr_) in zip(fr,to,cr):
    ax.quiver(*from_, *to_, colors=colr_)
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved my issue by using

cols = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'r', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'b', 'b']

Which now cycles through the colours correctly (assuming that there is only three lines being drawn).

Comment: @TomMcLean Nice try. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, that is a much better way!