# How to plot with matplotlib a 3d quiver plot with color gradient for length? gives error "ValueError: object too deep for desired array"

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I want to indicate the length of the quivers (are the arrows calls quivers?) by color coding them. That is no issue with 2d quiver plots. [Here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/quiver_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-quiver-demo-py) it is done. With 3d projection it fails hard. This code reproduces the issue.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make the grid
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.8))

# Make the direction data for the arrows
u = np.sin(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
v = -np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.sin(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
w = (np.sqrt(2.0 / 3.0) * np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) *
     np.sin(np.pi * z))
M = np.sqrt(u**2 + v**2 + w**2)
ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, M)

plt.show()
```

this produces a long traceback within a couple of matplotlib files and ends with

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

How can I avoid this issue and color-code my quivers?

Comment: What is `M` supposed to be ?

Comment: @venky__ mathematically its the length of the 3d vectors. The same approach is used here to achive the effect of color grading the arrows: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/quiver_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-quiver-demo-py

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420504/adding-colors-to-a-3d-quiver-plot-in-matplotlib

Comment: I did. I don't see how it can be applied to the length issue

Comment: scrolling all the way down, i see that it is useful and how it could be done. @venky__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @venky__ pointed out, there has been discussion about similar things before. I put that into a subroutine and adjusted for arrow length, even taking into account complex numbers in my arrays. [image: example graph]

```
def plot_3d_quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w):
    c = np.sqrt(np.abs(v) ** 2 + np.abs(u) ** 2 + np.abs(w) ** 2)
    c = (c.ravel() - c.min()) / c.ptp()
    # Repeat for each body line and two head lines
    c = np.concatenate((c, np.repeat(c, 2)))
    # Colormap
    c = plt.cm.jet(c)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, colors=c, length=0.1)
    plt.show()
```