# Different colours for arrows in 3D quiver plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 3D plot in quiver, I need to pass colour list of strings to specify the colours of arrows. How can this be done?

e.g colour[i,j,k]= 'red'or 'blue'

```
from matplotlib.cm import colors

ax = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15)).add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, color = colour, length=0.1, normalize=True)
```

Comment: Maybe [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420504/adding-colors-to-a-3d-quiver-plot-in-matplotlib) could help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful how to create the color list for quivers. Read the comment in the code below.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import chain

x, y = np.mgrid[-5:5:5j, -5:5:5j]
z = np.zeros_like(x)
u, v, w = x, y, np.ones_like(x)

# each quiver is composed of three lines:
# * one line for the stem.
# * two lines for the head.
# Let's say you have N quivers. To apply the same color
# to each quiver (stem + head), the `colors` list must be:
# colors = ["c_stem1", ..., "cstem_N", "chead_1", "chead_1", ..., "chead_N", "chead_N"]

get_color = lambda i: ["r", "g", "b"][i % 3]
stem_colors = [get_color(i) for i, t in enumerate(u.ravel())]
head_colors = [(c, c) for c in stem_colors]
colors = stem_colors + list(chain(*head_colors))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")
ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, colors=colors, normalize=True)
ax.set_zlim(-1, 2)
plt.show()
```